# 1 post displays correctly on category page while another post doesn't appear on its category page

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

In wordpress my archive.php page is displaying my two test posts as:

```
Post Name 1, and
This entry was posted in 'MyCategory1' on March 02, 2013
```

the second one as:

```
Post Name 2; and
This entry was posted in 'MyCategory2' on March 02, 2013
```

Both posts have been added under a custom post type called `projects`.

Both `MyCategory1` and `MyCategory2` shown above are links with a destination of:

`Mysite/category/MyCategory1` or `MyCategory2` for the second link.

Following the `MyCategory1` link displays the post correctly, it displays like on the archive page as title and the reference to it's category and only shows the post that's under MyCategory1, MyCategory2 no longer appears, this is correct.

But following the second link MyCategory2 displays a message:

```
Nothing Found
Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.
```

Any ideas why this might be happening and not showing the post that's under this category? The category link is created dynamically and so I cannot see why its not finding the 2nd post on the category page but is providing the link to it's category page?

Please note I have added the following code into category.php loop to query the posts to display from custom post types as well as just the ordinary standard WP post type:

```
// Modify the default loop, include custom post types
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => 'any' ) );
query_posts( $args );

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Any help and suggestions appreciated. I visited the permalinks page to try and refresh this in case there was an issue there but still no result. ? I'm a bit baffled.

I've just added a third category as well and tried this. It also does not display and returns 'Nothing Found'. So the only post category that's displaying correctly at 
`Sitename/category/MyCategoryName` is the first one.

My Category Base and Tag Base settings under permalinks are currently blank and therefore using the WP defaults.

Thanks

---

I have made some progress. If I use `?post_type=projects` at the end of the url then the category displays the project's posts for that category correctly. So I think the problem lies in that the default wp categories are not pulling in the custom post type 'Projects' posts successfully within the loop.

So this link works:

`http://localhost/Sitename/category/CategoryB?post_type=projects`

But how can I make the below link display the same as the link above?

`http://localhost/Sitename/category/CategoryA`

I think I need to query the posts some how so that it shows posts from the custom projects post type without the need to use ?post_type=projects.

?? Any ideas?

Comment: Check that both posts are published and that the one post is not a draft, or private, or something like that. Also, enable [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) if it is not already turned on and see if the broken page generates any useful messages.

Comment: all published and not private. After enabling Debugging, first category continues to work no errors, the two categories that are not working show the following message: 'Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\SiteName\wp-content\plugins\magic-fields-2\main.php on line 322'. This is followed by a Call Stack. Any ideas?

Comment: Notices aren't fatal but that is the only thing to go on that I see. Disable that "magic-fields-2" plugin and see if that helps.

Comment: The Magic Fields plugin plays a massive part in the whole of my setup, disabling it isn't really an option as that disables most of my site unfortunately. It provides all the custom fields, custom taxonomy's and more that I need.

Comment: I don't mean that you disable it permanently, just long enough to see if it contributes to the problem. You need to find the problem before you can fix it.

Comment: okay, I tried to deactivate the plugin and got a fatal error: 'Fatal error: Class 'mf_custom_fields' not found in C:\wamp\www\SiteName\wp-content\themes\ChildThemeName\functions.php on line 51'. would this be because debugging is still as true?

Comment: I turned off debugging and it still errors as above. It errors now when trying to access the plugins page, not just the Magic Fields plugin? Do you know how I can fix this?